# How do I get to the bottom of an ELUSIVE 500 Internal Server Error - in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The error can be seen: https://gist.github.com/916514#file_gistfile6.txt on line 24 & 44.

But the development.log doesn't provide any meaningful information.

I am using OS X & Textmate.

The error is produced whenever I update/edit a comment and submit it. What happens is that, as you can see in the log (https://gist.github.com/916514#file_gistfile6.txt  lines 11 - 15) that the updated comment has been pushed to the db and even retried on line 29.

However, once I press the 'save' button, the interface refreshes (via AJAX) - but the updated comment is not shown. It shows the original comment.

For anyone interested, all the relevant code is here: https://gist.github.com/916514

Is there a debugger or something I can get that can help me get more useful information about what is causing this error ? Or if you spot anything in that code that can tell me why it is throwing that error, I would REALLLLLY appreciate it.

I am using Thin Webserver.

Thanks.

Edit1: Took out this code, because it wasn't helping.

Edit2: I have narrowed down the issue to the 500 Internal Error.

When I comment out the format.js line in the update controller, and replace it with a plain line as follows:

```
format.js   { head :ok }
#format.js { render :partial => "comments/show", :locals => {:comment => @comment}, :layout => false, :status => :updated }
```

I no longer get the error. But now, the edit functionality does not work. When I press 'edit', it doesn't load the form with the updated comment. It simply loads an empty form. What should my format.js look like ?

Comment: you can try to wrap the smelly code in begin..rescue and print the stack trace with `rescued_exception.backtrace.join("\n")` and raise the exception again to keep breaking your code breaking until it is fixed properly

Comment: have you tried debugger on your controller and executing the code line by line?

Comment: @corroded which debugger ? Is there something that comes with Rails that I should be using ? Forgive the ignorant question, but this is the first time I am having to do this - just learning Rails. 

@Rubish tried, what I think, is something similar as recommended by @ZoltarSpeaks in the Answer and this is what I got: https://gist.github.com/916514#file_ajax%20header%20response Does anything jump out at you ?

Comment: put debugger in your controller. you should have ruby-debug as a gem though. then when you try to access that action, your rails app will stop in irb so you can check your app line by line

Answer (score 1):

You should get the Firebug FF Addon and check what the headers are returning via your AJAX call in the 'Console' tab. That might help you to debug a bit better.

In particular looking at the "Response" from your request to post the comment should uncover some clues.

[image: Screengrab of a Response code on Friebug]

The reason for your code failing should appear here.

Also if nothing clear comes through here, my next step would be to try and raise the params in the controller to double check the comment attributes are making it through via the AJAX request. try this in the first line of your Edit method in your controller:

```
raise params.inspect.to_s
```

This will stop your system in its tracks and throw back the params the controller is receiving in the "Response" area of "Console" in Firebug.

Comment: FF or Firebug ? Ohh...u said Firebug....sorry, thought you said Firefox FF addon. My bad. Will post those.

Comment: Ok I got some info, but it's a wall of text. Not sure what I am looking at. Here it is https://gist.github.com/916514#file_ajax%20header%20response, is there anything that jumps out at you ?

Comment: Line 200 of the output you have your parameters. Is everything there that you expect to be able to save the model?

Comment: Yep...looks so. Even includes the body of the new edit - which is line 208.

Comment: Ok you need to start trying to debug this logically. Taking out any unnecessary complexity from the scenario will help you; the AJAX at this stage. I would remove the AJAX from the scenario and try and debug the method as a regular html form. It will be easier to work out the bug that way. Let me know if you unearth any further information about the bug.